# Kubernetes google cloud composer with gitlab ci yaml file

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I am working on the deployment of a gitlab CI pipeline to trigger a google cloud composer DAG 
Below is the .yaml I wrote :

```
stages:
- deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get --only-upgrade install kubectl google-cloud-sdk
    - gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
    - gsutil cp   plugins/*.py   ${PLUGINS_BUCKET}
    - gsutil cp   dags/*.py   ${DAGS_BUCKET}
    - kubectl get pods
    - gcloud composer environments run ${COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT}  --location ${ENVIRONMENT_LOCATION}   trigger_dag   -- ${DAG_NAME}
```

Unfortunately, the execution of the pipleine  fails with the error below :

```
     $ gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
Updated property [core/project].
$ gsutil cp   plugins/*.py   ${PLUGINS_BUCKET}
Copying file://plugins/dataproc_custom_operators.py [Content-Type=text/x-python]...
/ [0 files][    0.0 B/  2.3 KiB]                                                
/ [1 files][  2.3 KiB/  2.3 KiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/2.3 KiB.                                      
$ gsutil cp   dags/*.py   ${DAGS_BUCKET}
copying file://dags/frrm_infdeos_workflow.py [Content-Type=text/x-python]...
/ [0 files][    0.0 B/  3.3 KiB]                                                
/ [1 files][  3.3 KiB/  3.3 KiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/3.3 KiB.                                      
$ gcloud composer environments run ${COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT}  --location ${ENVIRONMENT_LOCATION}   trigger_dag   -- ${DAG_NAME}
kubeconfig entry generated for europe-west1-nameenvironment-a5456e0c-gke.
ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.run) No running GKE pods found. If the environment was recently started, please wait and retry.
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Do you have any idea about how to fix this please ? 
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as @scalacode.  For me, the solution was that the gitlab-runner was running in a different GCP Project than the Composer Environment, so it failed without specifying that error.  Running a gitlab-runner in the same project as the Composer Environment fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

It seems Composer is unable to retrieve information about the pods/GKE cluster. This could be for a number of reasons ranging from the GKE cluster not creating the nodes to the pods being in a crash loop.

I notice in the script you did not [“get-credentials”](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials) to authenticate to the cluster. When running commands on a GKE cluster through CLI, traditionally you would first have to authenticate to the cluster first with [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials). To do this with composer:

```
gcloud composer environments describe ${COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT} --location ${ENVIRONMENT_LOCATION} --format="get(config.gkeCluster)"
```

This will return something of the form: projects/PROJECT/zones/ZONE/clusters/CLUSTER Then run:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${CLUSTER} --zone ${ZONE}
```

Once you have authenticated to the cluster in the script, see if it is now able to complete. If not, try running [kubectl get pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get) to see what is happening with the pods/if they exist.

If you see many pods restarting or generally not in the “running/completed” state, the issue could be with the pod configuration.
If you don’t see pods at all, the deployment may have failed. Check the deployment with command [kubectl get deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get).

The deployments airflow-scheduler, airflow-sqlproxy, & airflow-worker should be present. If those three deployments are not present, the environment was likely tampered with, & it would be easiest to make a new environment.

Comment: @scalacode, did this solve your issue?  If not, what steps did you take to resolve it.  I too am having this issue.

Comment: I _am_ authenticating with a service account first, and am still having an issue.  I ran `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` and `kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces` and they all return active pods/deployments including those you list.  The issue lies somewhere else.

Comment: When running the `get-credentials` from Cloud Composer, I got the following error : `ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'` and the same command works locally.